# http/2 Pushed javascript not loading

Tags: node.js, express, http2

I'm using the spdy nodejs library to push down my javascript bundles when a request comes in.

```
spdy
    .createServer(options, (req, res) => {
        // TODO - figure out why the javascript doesnt load on the client
        if (res.push) {
            console.log("Pushing...");
            // push vendor bundle
            const bundleStream = res.push(`/js/client.js`, {
                status: 200,
                method: "GET",
                request: { accept: "*/*" },
                response: { "content-type": "application/javascript" },
            });

            bundleStream.on("error", (e: any) => console.error(e));
            bundleStream.end();
            // push main bundle
            const vendorStream = res.push(`/js/vendor.js`, {
                status: 200,
                method: "GET",
                request: { accept: "*/*" },
                response: { "content-type": "application/javascript" },
            });
            vendorStream.on("error", (e: any) => console.error(e));
            vendorStream.end();
        }
        return app(req as any, res as any);
    })
    .listen(port, (err: any) => {
```

where `app` is an express js middleware. Everything works normally if it's not an https server, but once https has been configured the push shows up in the request but content is empty (no javascript executes)

[image: push request showing up]

It looks like the files have zero content, but I know the server knows how to serve them because it does so correctly when push is not enabled.

It's driving me nuts so any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I presume the JavaScript files are normally served by Node and not served by a web server (e.g. Apache or Nginx) in front of Node?

Comment: Correct. I'm using express with middleware to render react, and to serve static assets. It works normally if I disable the push so not sure what's going on here

Comment: Could you post the output of `nghttp -nv https://<url>` ? That will print the detail of the received HTTP/2 frames.

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt here is the output: https://pastebin.com/Wuju0HR2

Comment: The trace shows that the server is sending empty data frames. I would suggest you open an issue with node, since http/2 is a relatively new addition there https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues

Comment: Yeah, it's weird that it works without it enabled. I thought maybe it was an issue with the filename, but it's supposed to match from the client's perspective, correct?

Comment: Filed an issue per your suggestion. Hopefully this gets resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
bundleStream.end();
```

and:

```
vendorStream.end();
```

You've to pass the file output to the `response.end()` method, if you don't specify it, the stream doesn't recognize from where it needs to load the file. So your call to `end` should be like this ones:

```
bundleStream.end(fs.readFileSync('path-to-bundle-file', 'utf-8'));
vendorStream.end(fs.readFileSync('path-to-vendor-file', 'utf-8'));
```